# React native problem with tailwind css not being fully applied

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I need help figure out where is the error.
This is my github repo link: https://github.com/khouloudhaddad/food-delivery
TailwindCss not working iside folders

This is my github repo link: https://github.com/khouloudhaddad/food-delivery

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^3.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.17",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "expo": "^50.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
  };
};
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

[Project stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kphM.png)

I followed the documentation to add tailwind css to my react-native application, but encountered many errors, so I downgraded the tailwind version to 3.3.2 as some people suggested but tailwind styles are only applied in App.js.